# How do I use internet in ubuntu using nokia mobile?

Tags: ubuntu, mobile-phone, tethering

I have a Nokia mobile phone but I don't have Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu 
But I have PC suit for windows.
How can I use that setup for ubuntu or give me any other way to use internet 
using Nokia mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too hard, I do it with mine. (Nokia N95 / Ubuntu 9.10)

- First, plugin the phone with the USB cable (don't know how to do it via Bluetooth),
- on the phone, choose "PC Suite"
- on Ubuntu, right-click the network manager (the icon at the top-right) and choose 'edit connections'
- Click the 'Mobile Broadband' tab
- Click 'Add' at the top right
- Choose your mobile from the list (or whichever one is most similar)
- Follow the prompts to fill in your username/password (If you didn't do this on your phone, you don't need to now -- defaults should be good, but it depends on your service provider)

You can set that connection to be 'auto', then whenever you plugin the phone and click 'pc suite' in the future, the internet will just happen.

Comment: @Omkant: Would you mind marking the answer as the accepted solution if it worked for you? :)

Answer (score 2):

Connecting the phone to the computer should allow you to create a GSM profile in NetworkManager so that you can connect.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring mobile via usb

- First, plugin the phone with the USB cable (don't know how to do it via Bluetooth),

  - on the phone, choose "PC Suite"
  - on Ubuntu, right-click the network manager (the icon at the top-right) and choose **Edit Connections**
- Click the 'Mobile Broadband' tab
- Click 'Add' at the top right
- Choose your mobile from the list (or whichever one is most similar)
- Follow the prompts to fill in your username/password (If you didn't do this on your phone, you don't need to now -- defaults should be good, but it depends on your service provider)