# How to connect to the internet in Opensuse 11.2?

Tags: tethering, opensuse-11.2

How do I connect internet in Opensuse 11.2 KDE environment? I have an Airtel Macromax USB plug and play device.

Comment: Which of the dozen Micromax thingys do you have?

Comment: from which u connect internet..i.e usb data internet card.

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/135293/how-do-i-use-internet-in-ubuntu-using-nokia-mobile

While Q&A is for Ubuntu, the steps should be the same, since I believe both use NetworkManager

Comment: no itsnot the same.i knew in ubuntu.while clicking on nework.the screen will open up the instruction for chosing the internet option while for network for reliance,airtel or othere etc.in this opensuse nothing is given here open.even network manager is not being opened.i hav installed the opensuse11.2 properly.

Comment: I asked for the exact type...there are over a dozen different devices available, and all are different.